# Deep Link to iOS app without bringing the app to the foreground

Tags: ios, swift, url, mobile, deep-linking

I am wondering if it is possible to send a deep link to an app without the app opening up.  I understand the main purpose of the deep link is to open the app to a specific section.

However, I'm trying to send the deep link from a URL to confirm of the app is install or not.  (not trying to open it from the URL)

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIApplication's canOpenURL: method for this

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:

Comment: I'm confused... how would i call that from a deep link on a website URL?

Comment: Oh you mean on a website from mobile safari. Like in javascript? That isn't possible right now.